# generate all possible strings with 0 and 1 (given length)

Tags: java, string

i need a function in java that give a (int length) as input and print all possible strings with '0' and '1' letters.
this is not a permutation because number of 0 s and 1 s are different in each possible string
EXAMPLE: length=3

- 111
- 110
- 100
- 000
- 001
- 011
- 010
- 101

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Where's your code so far?

Comment: convert to binary number from `000` to `111` do a loop.

Comment: i had no idea to do that in a simple way...

Comment: Recursion should do the job as well.

Comment: Hi @user3084088, welcome to Stack Overflow. The reason, as you have gathered, for the downvotes is mainly due to the lack of any code. It's not just a "I'm not going to do your work for you" reason though. You will learn nothing if it is done for you. I say that from first hand experience. It is only from trying, from writing some code, doing some reading that you will crack it, and you will understand it. Giving you a full answer deprives you of the feeling of achievement, and more importantly from learning. Try a simple loop that prints something, then modify it, and use a pen and paper!

Comment: I'd just add that you should read up on [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help). They're great resources and with a little practice you'll get some truly great help on this site. I've had my bacon saved on a few occasions, and greatly appreciate it! Best of luck with the code.

Comment: Use Stack Overflow for learning, not direct assignment solving my friend. Show some efforts to be eligible to receive some help from the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something with `2^N` (`N` can takes as length ). Then convert `0-2^N` to binary and use proper binary formating. The you can have what you looking for.

First step- get `2^N`

```
double twosPow = Math.pow(2, occurrence);
```

Now iterate from `0` up to `twosPow`. and convert number to binary

Second step- how to convert int to binary?

```
Integer.toBinaryString(k); // 0<=k<  twosPow
```

Third step- format binary

```
String.format("%" + length + "s",binary).replace(" ", "0")
```